# pythonで指定したフォルダにファイルの書き込みを行いたい

Tags: python

エラーが表示され、画像ファイルを指定したフォルダに書き込むことができません。
指定フォルダを`C:\\Users\\???\\Desktop\\pics_directry`にするとファイルの書き込みはできます。フォルダ（pics_directry）にはたくさんフォルダがあり、この中に画像ファイルを書き込みたいです。

<エラー文>

```
with open(savepath, mode="wb") as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
```

<実行した内容>

```
url = "https://......"

class AppURLopener(req.FancyURLopener):
    version = "Mozilla/5.0"
opener = AppURLopener()
res = opener.open(url) 

soup = BeautifulSoup(res, "html.parser")
links = soup.div.center.find_all("a") 
target_links = [link.get('href') for link in links] 

for img_links in target_links:
　　　　o = urlparse(img_links)
　　　　savepath = 'C:\\Users\\???\\Desktop\\pics_directry\\' + o.netloc + o.query
　　　　if not os.path.exists(savepath):
　　　　　　　　print("makedirs=", savepath)
　　　　　　　　os.makedirs(savepath)
　　　　res = opener.open(img_links)
　　　　soup = BeautifulSoup(res, "html.parser")
　　　　img_links = soup.select(" div > p > a > img")
　　　　img_target_links = [link.get('src') for link in img_links]
　　　　print(img_target_links)
　　　　for s in img_target_links:
　　　　　　　　re = requests.get(s)
　　　　　　　　print('Download:', s)
　　　　　　　　with open(savepath, mode="wb") as f:
　　　　　　　　　　　　f.write(re.content)
　　　　　　　　　　　　time.sleep(0.1)
```

※追記
やはり自分では作成したフォルダへ画像ファイルを直接書き込むことができませんでした。なので、画像ファイル書き込みを他のフォルダ上で行いその後 glob()やshutil.move()などを使って指定のフォルダに移動しました。やりたかったことは一応達成できました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: モジュールimportは省いています。

Comment: 「保存先のフォルダにアクセス権が無い」とエラーになっていますが、心当たりはないですか？(保存先のユーザーフォルダと実行ユーザーは同じ？保存先フォルダが読み取り専用などになっていないか、等) / 動作には影響ないでしょうが、"directory"が正しい綴りです。単に"pics"フォルダにした方がすっきりするかなと個人的には思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。読み取り専用にはなっていないと思いますが、やはり他のフォルダへは保存できているので、os.makedirs(savepath)で作ったフォルダに問題があるんですかね。フォルダにos.chmod()で権限付けたりしたんですがどうもうまくいきません。

Comment: ちなみに最後のfor文を変えると
for s in img_target_links:try:
            data = req.urlopen(s).read() 
            with open(savepath, mode="wb") as f:
                f.write(data)
                time.sleep(0.1)
        except urllib.error.URLError as e:
            print(e)
            time.sleep(0.1)
HTTP Error 403Lforbiddenが返ってきます

Comment: 「保存が出来るフォルダ」と「出来ないフォルダ」の違いは何でしょうか？同じユーザーフォルダ以下で名前が違うだけ？それとも(出来る方は)Cドライブ直下などまったく別の場所？ / 質問は後からでも [編集] できるので、追加の情報などがあれば直接本文に反映した方が目に留まりやすくなります。

Comment: @cubick♦コメントありがとうございます。いろいろ試してみます。

Comment: (代替案でも)解決した場合は質問文に直接含めてしまうのではなく、ぜひ「個別の回答」として投稿してください。スタック・オーバーフローでは自己回答も歓迎されますし、質問と回答の形に分かれていた方が情報を参照する人にとってもわかりやすくなります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.makedirs`でフォルダを作り、その**フォルダパスをopenすると**`permission denied`エラーになります。
[本家SOの類似回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21786209/8248751)

```
#エラーサンプル
import os
os.makedirs("hoge")
with open("hoge", "w") as f:
  f.write("fuga")
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'hoge'

親フォルダを作るようにコードを書き換えればうまくいかないでしょうか。

```
savepath = 'C:\\Users\\???\\Desktop\\pics_directry\\' + o.netloc + o.query
savedir = os.path.dirname(savepath)
if not os.path.exists(savedir):
    print("makedirs=", savedir)
    os.makedirs(savedir)
```

**追記:**

Windows 10, Python 3.6.6で下記のサンプルコードを実行すると、手元の環境では正常終了しました。
サンプルコードでは`o.query='s=32&d=identicon&r=PG'`でフォルダ名に無効な文字列が入るのを回避しています。
`print(o)`や`print(savepath)`などの出力内容または実行可能なコードを追記していただくと、より具体的な回答を得やすいかも知れません。

```
import os
import requests
import time
import urllib.request as req
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/52311/"

class AppURLopener(req.FancyURLopener):
    version = "Mozilla/5.0"
opener = AppURLopener()
res = opener.open(url) 

soup = BeautifulSoup(res, "html.parser")
targets = soup.find_all("img")

for img in targets:
    if not img.has_attr('width'):
        continue
    if img['width'] == '0':
        continue
    s = img['src']
    o = urlparse(s)
    desktop_path = os.getenv("HOMEDRIVE") + os.getenv("HOMEPATH") + '\\Desktop'
    savepath = desktop_path + '\\pics_directry\\' + o.netloc + o.path.replace('/', '\\')
    savedir = os.path.dirname(savepath)
    if not os.path.exists(savedir):
        print("makedirs=", savedir)
        os.makedirs(savedir)
    print('Download:', s)
    re = requests.get(s)
    with open(savepath, mode="wb") as f:
        f.write(re.content)
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: かわらず同じエラーを返してきました。PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Comment: サンプルコードありがとうございます。いろいろ試してみてまた質問させてください。